# Cannot resolve symbol @TextIndexed and cannot resolve symbol TextCriteria

Tags: spring, spring-data-mongodb

I'm trying to change the version of Spring Data MongoDB to 1.6.M1, but the problem still the same.

How the fix the import of:

```
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.index.TextIndexed;
```

and

```
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.query.TextCriteria;
```

This is the `pom.xml`, what do I need to change?

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

        <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
        <groupId>org.sab</groupId>
        <artifactId>sampleApp</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <packaging>war</packaging>
        <name>Sample App</name>
        <description>Sample App</description>

        <properties>
                <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>

                <!-- Spring Framework -->
                <spring.version>3.2.0.RELEASE</spring.version>
                <spring.security.core.version>3.1.3.RELEASE</spring.security.core.version>

                <!-- Mongo DB driver & Spring Data MongoDB -->
                <spring.data.mongodb.version>1.1.1.RELEASE</spring.data.mongodb.version>

                <mongodb.driver.version>2.10.1</mongodb.driver.version>

                <!-- Java Servlet -->
                <javax.servlet-api.version>3.0.1</javax.servlet-api.version>
                <javax.jstl-taglibs.version>1.2</javax.jstl-taglibs.version>

                <!-- Miscellaneous Dependencies -->
                <jackson.version>2.1.1</jackson.version>
                <log4j.version>1.2.14</log4j.version>

                <!-- Plugins -->
                <maven.compiler.plugin.version>2.3.2</maven.compiler.plugin.version>
                <maven.war.plugin.version>2.1.1</maven.war.plugin.version>
        </properties>

        <dependencies>
                <!-- Spring Core -->
                <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
                        <version>${spring.version}</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
                        <version>${spring.version}</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
                        <version>${spring.version}</version>
                </dependency>

                <!-- Logger -->
                <dependency>
                        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
                        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
                        <version>${log4j.version}</version>
                        <type>jar</type>
                        <scope>compile</scope>
                </dependency>


                <!-- Javax Servlet. This needs to be included for runtime only! -->
                <dependency>
                        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
                        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
                        <version>${javax.servlet-api.version}</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
                        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
                        <version>${javax.jstl-taglibs.version}</version>
                </dependency>

                <!-- Jackson JSON processor -->
                <dependency>
                        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                        <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
                        <version>${jackson.version}</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                        <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
                        <version>${jackson.version}</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
                        <version>${jackson.version}</version>
                </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-mongodb</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>



                <!-- Spring Data MongoDB -->
         <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-mongodb</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.data.mongodb.version}</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- MongoDB Java Driver -->
                <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
                        <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
                        <version>${mongodb.driver.version}</version>
                        <type>jar</type>
                        <scope>compile</scope>
                </dependency>

                <!-- Spring Security -->
                <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
                        <version>${spring.security.core.version}</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
                        <version>${spring.security.core.version}</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
                        <version>${spring.security.core.version}</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
                        <version>${spring.security.core.version}</version>
                </dependency>
        <!-- Jsoup  -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jsoup</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsoup</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.1</version>
        </dependency>
        </dependencies>
        <build>
                <finalName>sampleqa</finalName>

                <plugins>
                        <plugin>
                                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                                <version>${maven.compiler.plugin.version}</version>
                                <configuration>
                                        <source>1.6</source>
                                        <target>1.6</target>
                                </configuration>
                        </plugin>
                        <plugin>
                                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                                <version>${maven.war.plugin.version}</version>
                                <configuration>
                                        <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                                </configuration>
                        </plugin>
                </plugins>
        </build>
        <repositories>
                <!-- For main Spring releases -->
                <repository>
                        <id>org.springframework.maven.release</id>
                        <name>Spring Maven Release Repository</name>
                        <url>http://maven.springframework.org/release</url>
                        <releases>
                                <enabled>true</enabled>
                        </releases>
                        <snapshots>
                                <enabled>false</enabled>
                        </snapshots>
                </repository>
                <!-- For Java Releases -->
                <repository>
                        <id>java.net2</id>
                        <name>Repository hosting the jee6 artifacts</name>
                        <url>http://download.java.net/maven/2</url>
                </repository>
                <repository>
                        <id>jboss</id>
                        <name>JBoss repository</name>
                        <url>https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/repositories/releases</url>
                </repository>
        </repositories>
</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I am not wrong your compiler is giving error on this line

```
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.index.TextIndexed;
```

However this class is present in following path

```
\spring-data-mongodb-1.6.0.RELEASE.jar.zip\org\springframework\data\mongodb\core\index
```

To get rid of this issue check in your classpath this jar `spring-data-mongodb-1.6.0.XXXX` is present or not.
If its present  unzip the same and check that class is there or not.

If class is there then check that any other jar there in your classpath with same name and having different version if it is just delete it from classpath and check the compilation issue.

Its better to have clean deployment sometime old jar dont remove from classpath due to out side access issue can cause the problem.